# How to add a fileupload method in my existing mav controller to accept ajax file upload submit

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, file-upload, controller

My situation is: I have a Spring MVC project is running now, I need to include a file in normal form object to submit to server side to handling.

I did quite lots research recently, I found there is no way to submit a file in a regular form as file upload submit form has to configured to support file encode (enctype="multipart/form-data"). it is impossible in regular form.

Ajax provides a way to do the file uploading in javascript by javascript function call, but they need a individual servlet to listen to the javascript call. My project already did everything in modelandview controller to handle form object and model object logic.

My question is: May I add a file upload method in my modelandview controller to listen to my Ajax function call? If it is true, what's looks like?

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while works on this issue, I found some thing is very interesting. If I want to use some thing else in my Spring MVC controller. I have change my controller class to "extends MultiActionController", which means make the controller to support multiAction, and then you can add other class and action in Spring MVC modelandview style controller, even you can use "webservlet" or "ResponseBody" style controller functions in your MVC controller, you don't need create other new controller to support Ajax controller, you only need update your existing controller by adding some functions. it is much easy to manage you existing code too.